# React component not displaying the correct data from Redux. Console log shows the correct data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cordova, redux

The component which would show the number of files at this moment (currently shows 0).

When the "logstate" button is pressed it does log the number 8 as it should.

So I think that the redux store is getting updated but the component itself is not showing the correct data. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { AppState } from "src/state/setup/rootReducer";
import { BapFileEntry, getBapFilesFromState, getWizardState, WizardState } from "../../state/reducers/wizardReducer";
import { getBapFiles } from "../../state/actions/wizardActions";
import "./SelectPlatformView.scss";
export interface SelectPlatformViewProps {
    nextStep: () => void;
    listDir: (path: string) => any;
    getBapFiles: (value: BapFileEntry[]) => void;
    bapFiles: BapFileEntry[];
}
// function to list files inside a path
// (path: "file:///storage/emulated/0/bap/" will list all the .bap files inside "Internal storage/bap" folder)
function listDir(path: string): BapFileEntry[] {
    var bapFiles: BapFileEntry[] = [];
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        path,
        function(directory) {
            var reader = directory.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(
                function(entries: any) {
                    // iterate over each file in the directory and add them to another array
                    entries.forEach((item: any) => {
                        if (item.isFile) {
                            bapFiles.push(item);
                        }
                    });
                },
                function(err: any) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
    return bapFiles;
}
export class SelectPlatfromView extends React.Component<SelectPlatformViewProps> {
    // bapFilesArray: BapFileEntry[];
    constructor(props: SelectPlatformViewProps) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const files = listDir("file:///storage/emulated/0/bap/");
        this.props.getBapFiles(files);
    }
    continue = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ViewContainer">
                <h1>Select platform</h1>
                <div className="PlatformListContainer">
                    <h1>{this.props.bapFiles.length}</h1> // <-- this should also show 8
                </div>
                <button className="WizardButton" onClick={this.continue}>
                    Next
                </button>
                <button className="WizardButton" onClick={() => console.log(this.props.bapFiles.length)}>
                    Logstate
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state: AppState): Partial<SelectPlatformViewProps> {
    return {
        bapFiles: getBapFilesFromState(state)
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch): Partial<SelectPlatformViewProps> {
    return {
        getBapFiles: (value: BapFileEntry[]) => {
            dispatch(getBapFiles(value));
        }
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SelectPlatfromView);
```

wizardActions.ts

```js
import { BapFileEntry } from "../reducers/wizardReducer";
export enum WizardActions {
    GetBapFiles = "WizardActions/GetBapFiles"
}
export type WizardAction = GetBapFiles;
export interface GetBapFiles {
    type: WizardActions.GetBapFiles;
    payload: BapFileEntry[];
}
export function getBapFiles(data: BapFileEntry[]): GetBapFiles {
    return { type: WizardActions.GetBapFiles, payload: data };
}
```

wizardReducer.ts

```js
import { WizardAction, WizardActions } from "../actions/wizardActions";
import { AppState } from "../setup/rootReducer";
export interface BapFileEntry {
    fullPath: string;
    isDirectory: boolean;
    isFile: boolean;
    name: string;
    nativeURL: string;
}
export interface WizardState {
    bapFiles: BapFileEntry[];
}
export const defaultWizardState: WizardState = {
    bapFiles: []
};
export function wizardReducer(state: WizardState = defaultWizardState, action: WizardAction): WizardState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case WizardActions.GetBapFiles:
            return { ...state, bapFiles: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export function getWizardState(state: AppState): WizardState {
    return state.wizard;
}
export function getBapFilesFromState(state: AppState): BapFileEntry[] {
    // console.log("got files from state");
    return state.wizard.bapFiles;
}
```

Comment: You are working with asynchronous API's, but you aren't notifying React about changes. You should convert the `listDir` function to return a Promise and wait before calling the  `getBapFiles` function.

Comment: @Christiaan I'll try that. Thank you, wasn't totally sure if I am dealing with async API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Christiaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790728/christiaan) I managed to render the data properly on the component by refactoring the listDir function as follows

```js
// function to list files inside a path
// (path: "file:///storage/emulated/0/bap/" will list all the .bap files inside "Internal storage/bap" folder)
function listDir(path: string): Promise<BapFileEntry[]> {
    var bapFiles: BapFileEntry[] = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, entry => {
            var reader = entry.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(
                (entries: BapFileEntry[]) => {
                    entries.forEach(item => {
                        if (item.isFile) {
                            bapFiles.push(item);
                        }
                    });
                    resolve(bapFiles);
                },
                (err: any) => {
                    reject(err);
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```